# Slot Machine in C program with loops

Tags: c, function, loops

I am trying to make random numbers and loops to create the slot machine. This is part of my Final project for my course. Once this is working program, I also am trying to make curses library as well. I have included the error messages in the below I am using `Code::Blocks` software I can download for free programming to use. I don't understand how this isn't working properly... Can anyone help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>

int intSlot1, intSlot2, intSlot3;

void fnGotoXY(short x, short y);
void fnSlotMachine();
void fnSlot1();
void fnSlot2();
void fnSlot3();

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    fnSlotMachine();
    while (1) {
        fnSlot1();
        fnSlot2();
        fnSlot3();
    }
}

void fnGotoXY(short x, short y)
{
    COORD pos = { x, y };
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), pos);
}

void fnSlotMachine()
{
    fnGotoXY(5, 5);
    printf(" x^---------------------------^x\n");
    printf("      |oOoOoOoOoOoOoOoOoOoOoOoOoOoOo|\n");
    printf("      \\_____________________________/\n");
    printf("      /__$$$__\\  /__$$$__\\  /__$$$__\\");
    fnGotoXY(5, 12);
    printf(" <*^*^*^*>  <*^*^*^*>  <*^*^*^*>");
}

void fnSlot1()
{
    Sleep(50);
    fnGotoXY(5, 9);
    intSlot1 = rand() % 9;
    printf(" | %i %i %i |\n", intSlot1, intSlot1, intSlot1);
    fnGotoXY(2, 10);
    printf("    | %i %i %i |\n", intSlot1, intSlot1, intSlot1);
    fnGotoXY(2, 11);
    printf("    | %i %i %i |", intSlot1, intSlot1, intSlot1);
}

void fnSlot2()
{
    Sleep(50);
    fnGotoXY(17, 9);
    intSlot2 = rand() % 9;
    printf("| %i %i %i |\n", intSlot2, intSlot2, intSlot2);
    fnGotoXY(17, 10);
    printf("| %i %i %i |\n", intSlot2, intSlot2, intSlot2);
    fnGotoXY(17, 11);
    printf("| %i %i %i |", intSlot2, intSlot2, intSlot2);
}


void fnSlot3()
{
    Sleep(50);
    fnGotoXY(27, 9);
    intSlot3 = rand() % 9;
    printf("| %i %i %i |\n", intSlot3, intSlot3, intSlot3);
    fnGotoXY(27, 10);
    printf("| %i %i %i |\n", intSlot3, intSlot3, intSlot3);
    fnGotoXY(27, 11);
    printf("| %i %i %i |", intSlot3, intSlot3, intSlot3);
}
```

Compiler by **Code::Blocks**:

```
C:\Users\Admin\Documents\PROGRAMMING\runner\main.c|16|undefined reference to `fnSlotMachine'|
C:\Users\Admin\Documents\PROGRAMMING\runner\main.c|18|undefined reference to `fnSlot1'|
C:\Users\Admin\Documents\PROGRAMMING\runner\main.c|60|undefined reference to `fnGotoXY'|
C:\Users\Admin\Documents\PROGRAMMING\runner\main.c|63|undefined reference to `fnGotoXY'|
C:\Users\Admin\Documents\PROGRAMMING\runner\main.c|65|undefined reference to `fnGotoXY'|
C:\Users\Admin\Documents\PROGRAMMING\runner\main.c|73|undefined reference to `fnGotoXY'|
C:\Users\Admin\Documents\PROGRAMMING\runner\main.c|76|undefined reference to `fnGotoXY'|
obj\Debug\main.o:C:\Users\Admin\Documents\PROGRAMMING\runner\main.c|78|more undefined references to `fnGotoXY' follow|
```

Comment: Code::Blocks is no compiler.

Comment: Also, when you write `void foo();` you most certainly want `void foo(void);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your opening and closing brackets `{` are incorrect.

In main you have not closed the `while` loop and have an extra closing bracket in function `fnSlot1`

These sort of issues can be easily caught by a consistent indentation scheme. In your program, you have differing spaces for each indent.

Comment: I would also suggest to use a different editor (than CodeBlocks). One, with a proper linter!